# Pass delegates to external C functions in D

Tags: c, delegates, function-pointers, d

How do I pass a delegate to an external C function taking a function pointer, in D?

Comment: Why exactly is this being downvoted?

Comment: Probably because you have a "C" tag. C programmers here on SO are fast on the trigger... At least that is my experience.

Comment: @OMGtechy I have tried stuff like simply passing the delegate, and trying to use the .funcptr property, of which neither worked. I am pretty sure I've seen people do it, but I can't find any examples on Google.

Comment: This might help: [link](http://dlang.org/interfaceToC.html)

Comment: @DejanLekic Alright, moved the "In D" bit to the end to force people to read all of it. :P

Comment: @OMGtechy All that says is that Delegates cannot directly be passed as function pointers, which I figured out already. Thanks anyway. :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let me cross post what I said on the newsgroup:

> How do I pass a delegate to an external C function taking a 
>   function pointer?

You can't do it directly in general, unless you can modify the C 
function, then you can hack around it, but a delegate and a 
regular function pointer are pretty different animals.

But perhaps you can magic hack it. Observe:

```
// a C function that needs a plain function
extern(C) void test(void function() f) {
    // pretend this is implemented in C
    f();
}

// just create a random delegate
void delegate() foo(int a) {
    return { import std.stdio; writeln(a); };
}

// what we want to work
void main() {
    auto dg = foo(10);
    dg(); // works

    //test(dg); // won't work
    test(bindDelegate(dg)); // we want this
}

// transform delegate into pointer..
import std.traits;
auto bindDelegate(T, string file = __FILE__, size_t line = __LINE__)(T t) if(isDelegate!T) {
    static T dg;

    dg = t;

    extern(C)
    static ReturnType!T func(ParameterTypeTuple!T args) {
            return dg(args);
    }

    return &func;
}
```

What bindDelegate does is create a special static variable and 
function for that specific call.  It is as if we wrote a separate 
function and global to hold it.

The `__FILE__`, `__LINE__` things are a filthy hack to make it 
instantiate a separate variable+function pair for different 
lines so the global variable holding the delegate won't be so 
easily overwritten.

Comment: I also just realized, since there's a global holding the delegate, it will always allocate a dynamic closure and the memory it points to will never be freed; the reference continues to exist forever. (Well, you could perhaps do another bindDelegate call with the same file and line params and null to clear it that way, but realistically who's gonna bother?) This is potentially good and bad: the good is C can use it with confidence that the GC won't sweep it up prematurely. The bad is, of course, the potential for a memory leak once you are all done with it. So just be aware of that caveat.

Comment: How about instead of taking a file and line you take a pointer to the class, and as string the method name? This way it can only be overwritten either by the object, or by another object on the same location. (meaning the original object was destroyed anyways)