# Why is this function seen as a delegate?

Tags: c, delegates, arguments, d, function-literal

In an attempt to wrap a C function taking callbacks, I encountered the problem of member functions being seen as delegates. The C function wouldn't take delegates, so I settled on something else instead:

```
extern(C) void onMouse(void delegate(int, int, int) nothrow callback)
{
    glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(handle,
        function void (GLFWwindow* h, int button, int action, int mods) nothrow
        {
            callback(button, action, mods);
        }
    );
}
```

As you can see, I'm passing to the callback setting function a function literal calling a delegate (which would be the member function I pass here).

However, it doesn't end up as I expect:

```
Error: function pointer glfwSetMouseButtonCallback (GLFWwindow*, extern (C) void function(GLFWwindow*, int, int, int) nothrow) is not callable using argument types (GLFWwindow*, void delegate(GLFWwindow* h, int button, int action, int mods) nothrow @system)
```

In the error, it shows the second parameter as being as the type `void delegate`.

**So. My question is: why does this happen?** As you can clearly see, it says `function void` in the code.

NOTE: I've seen this: [Pass delegates to external C functions in D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22845175/pass-delegates-to-external-c-functions-in-d).
The solution is apparently a hack. But I will try it if I cannot find a workaround on the internet.

Comment: Your main problem seems to be the *linkage* for the function - "C" and C++. To me it is not very clear what you *want* it to be - is "delegate" supposed to be of C or C++ linkage?

Comment: @tofro I'm afraid I do not understand. The delegate literal is just a function literal with a 'this' attached, making it incompatible with C and (for some reason) unable to be translated into a function literal with ease.

Comment: Watch the compiler messages closely. You have told it `glfwSetMouseButtonCallback ()`would take an `extern "C"` function pointer as second argument. But you are handing in a C++ function pointer (`delegate`) instead. Those two types are not compatible.

Comment: So, if I did `extern(C) void function(GLFWwindow*, int, int, int) cb = (h, button, action, mods) { callback(button, action, mods); };` then why doesn't that work either? and are you confusing D with C++?

Comment: I don't think this would compile anyway because your "function" is accessing a local variable, which means it is necessarily a delegate (function pointers can not access local variables, including parameters passed to the outside function). The error should probably say that instead of pretending it is a delegate, but regardless, this code should indeed be an error.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe Really? Before I had to use delegates, I passed a function literal that did access a local variable to the C function... and everything worked fine. Or am I misunderstanding what you mean? Anyways, I suppose that proved my thought that something was going on behind my back.

Comment: Can you post some of the code? If it was local and static, that's different. But the reason it is a delegate is local variables can change on each run of the function, so they need a pointer to the right data block. A delegate has that, a function doesn't.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe Oh, I think I get what you mean. My previous code was actually accessing static variables, which seems to explain some of the trouble I was having earlier with local variables. And the trouble was because it was somehow implicitly converted or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you declare it as function, it cannot be. It relies on the parameter you pass to `onMouse`. That parameter is a local variable, and accessing them in a function body makes them a delegate. All you can do is change the parameter to `function` and pass it with `&callback` (you'd need to add GLFWwindow as parameter then).

Alternatively, you can create a global list in which this callback puts events which you can then process in your main loop.

Comment: I really think that D should not implicitly convert the function literal into a delegate literal. That gave me quite a lot of confusion.